# How do I calculate daily data from minute data in Q without killing KDB?

Tags: kdb

I've written the following query:

```
select first(o), max(h), min(l), last(c), sum(v) by sym, t.date from disk
```

where 'disk' is a parted splayed disk table containing 160m rows.

When I run this query, all RAM gets consumed and then KDB dies.

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
My schema is:

```
c  | t f a
---| -----
t  | p    
o  | f    
h  | f    
l  | f    
c  | f    
v  | i    
sym| s   p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a helpful function in the `.Q` namespace, `.Q.dpft` here https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotq/#qdpft-save-table which saves tables splayed to a partitioned database, that you can wrap in a lambda and pass each date e.g.

```
q) / table might be called alltrades
q)table:([]date:"d"$100?7000+til 10;sym:100?`AAA`BBB`CCC;price:100?100.0)
q)table
date       sym price
-----------------------
2019.03.10 BBB 49.81119
2019.03.08 CCC 8.997612
2019.03.08 CCC 22.74166
2019.03.06 BBB 86.544
..
q) / below, t might be called trade
q){t::select from table where date=x; .Q.dpft[`:hdb; x; `sym;`t]}'[exec distinct date from table]
`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t`t
q) \\
user@host:~$ cd hdb
user@host:~/hdb$ ls
2019.03.02  2019.03.03  2019.03.04  2019.03.05  2019.03.06  2019.03.07  2019.03.08  2019.03.09  2019.03.10  2019.03.11  sym
user@host:~/hdb$ cd 2019.03.02
user@host:~/hdb/2019.03.02$ ls
t
user@host:~/hdb/2019.03.02$ cd t
user@host:~/hdb/2019.03.02/t$ ls
date  price  sym
```

where `hdb` is the directory path you want to save to, `sym` is the symbol column which will be automatically enumerated and `table` is the table in memory which you want to partition.

Comment: This worked exactly as described - thank you! I wasn't able to `select` easily on the resulting database though, which has left me a little lost. In terms of usage, how does working with a partitioned db differ from working with a normal splayed table? (feel free to link to the doc if it's easier, I just haven't been able to figure out the answer myself so far)

Comment: When using partitioned db's you can only use `select` statements, what trouble are you having? terrylynch was correct about not having a` date` column in your db, so when you are saving to disk you will use `{tab::select from table where t.date=x; .Q.dpft[\`:hdb; x; \`sym; \`tab]}'[exec distinct t.date from table]` (where `t` is your timestamp column as in the meta).

Answer (score 0):

`date` is a virtual column so it needs to be created every time you read the table into memory, so by grouping on the `date` column first this can speed up the query. I also think you can drop the `t` from `t.date`, i.e.

```
q) select first(o), max(h), min(l), last(c), sum(v) by date, sym from disk
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, I tried this, but I just got 'date' as an error. Do I need to rename my `t` column to be something else in order to get these virtual cols to work?

Comment: (PS switching the precedence of t.date and sym both result in oom crashes)

Comment: Have you partitioned the `disk` database by `date`?

Comment: No, only by `sym`. I added a copy of the `meta` to the post above.

Comment: It is common convention to partition by `date`, when you do this and run the query in my answer above it will be much quicker. If you want to stick with your structure you could try multithreading the process using `peach`, e.g. `{select max price by sym, t.date from disk where sym=x} peach sym` but you will need to instantiate the secondary threads when you start the q session using the `-s` flag, e.g. `q disk -s 8`.

Comment: Is it possible to partition by date automatically? I'm reading the docs here https://code.kx.com/q4m3/14_Introduction_to_Kdb%2B/#1433-creating-partitioned-tables and it seems like I have to manually create a table for each day.

Comment: I've added a method of doing this in my second answer.

Comment: I'm just rebuilding the db as partitions now, thanks to your answer! One question, I'm including a 'date' column when I save the data. Do I need to do that? (I think it's about 30 mins while it builds, so I'll soon find out!)

Comment: No you shouldn't have a date column in the table that you write down into each date slice, the date column will exist synthetically due to the date-partitioning of the database. Having a second column called "date" will cause problems